# How small can $\max_{x \ge 0} e^x f'(x)$ be in terms of $\max_{x \ge 0} e^x f(x)$ if $f \ge 0$, $f(0) = 0$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, maxima-minima

Assume that $f$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ such that

- $f$ is nonnegative and compactly supported,
- $f(0) = 0$,
- $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = 1$.

Denote
$$
a = \max_{x \ge 0} e^x f(x)
$$

> How small can
> $$b = \max_{x \ge 0} |e^x f'(x)|$$
> be in terms of $a$?

Since $g(x) := e^x f(x)$ is continuous, we have $a = g(y)$ for some $y > 0$. Clearly $g'(y) = 0$, hence
$$
a = g(y) = g(y) - g'(y) = e^yf(y) - e^yf(y) - e^y f'(y) = -e^y f'(y) \le \max_{x \ge 0} |e^x f'(x)| = b.
$$
This shows that $b \ge a$. Is it possible to obtain sharper estimate of $b$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: Title and body of your question differ considerably. People won't invest time before you decide what you really want to ask.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry for that. My original title was to long, and while I was trying to shorten it a little bit some misprints ocurs. Is it better now?